# How to group data in PHP inside the while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I query in a database and loop the result using while and heres the sample data retrieve:

```
echo $db->f("FirstName")."===".$db->f("Question")."=".$db->f("Answer")."<br>";

Michael===Q2=allergy
Michael===Q2=Hives
Michael===Q6=A lot
Michael===Q8_A=Daktacort
Michael===Q1=Itch
Michael===Q5=Smoke
Michael===Q8_A=Diprogenta
Christian===Q1=Stuffy
Christian===Q6=A lot
Christian===Q1=Clear
Christian===Q5=Pollen
```

How can I group them according to name and to their Q value?
I want something like this result:

```
Name          Q1           Q2                         ..... so on and so fort.
Michael      Itch          Hives, Allergy
Christian    Stuffy
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to do this in MySQL

```
SELECT FirstName,Question,GROUP_CONCAT(Answer) AS Answers
FROM <tables>
GROUP BY FirstName,Question
```

Comment: I cannot group them by name because answers are coming from different table also the Qvalues. Grouping them can only retrieve one answer and Q Value.

Comment: In that case please provide the table structure and some example data in your question (preferably the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some `INSERT INTO ...` lines).

Answer (score 0):

Use an array rather than a loop of discrete calls to a function.  Then you could have something like:

```
$data[0]["FirstName"] = "Michael";
$data[0]["Q1"] = "Itch";
$data[0]["Q2"] = "Hives, Allergy";
... etc
```

You can loop through this array when you want to display the data and present a table with discrete rows of associated information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function for that.

But keep the limitations of [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) in mind.